# Column name getting changed while importing column from excel in laravel excel

Tags: php, excel, laravel, phpexcel, laravel-excel

Hi am using laravel excel to import file from excel and getting the data but the column heading is getting changed and i need to keep is as same. For eg: column name is Mat_Type-1 then it get convert to mat_type_1.

Whereas i want to keep it as same to get some data out of the column.

Function in controller :

```
public function uploadexcel(Request $request){
// $this->validate($request, [
//  'importfile'  => 'required|mimes:xls,xlsx'
// ]);
    echo $path = $request->file('importfile');

    $array = Excel::toArray(new ProductsImport, $path);


    print_r($array);
}
```

Excel\Imports class:

namespace App\Imports;

```
  use App\Models\Admin\CarVariant;
  use App\Models\Admin\Product;
  use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
  use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
  use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
  use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithBatchInserts;
  use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithChunkReading;
  use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
  use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithValidation;
 class ProductsImport implements ToModel,WithHeadingRow
{
/**
* @param array $row
*
* @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
*/
public function model(array $row)
{
            // dd($row);

}

}
```

Any help is deeply appreciated. Tried multiple option but not working.

Comment: @ahackney Column name are dynamic and it will change want to read that column name and use the same. Got an option of HeadingRowFormatter but confused how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this. It's from a live project. I'm saving the file to a folder and getting the data in array then pressing it to datatable. No change in data-table name.

```
use App\Imports\ProductsImport;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;

public function import(Request $request)
{
    //Save the File
    if($request->hasFile('file'))
    {
        // Get the file with extension
        $filenameWithExt = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
        //Get the file name
        $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        //Get the ext
        $extension = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        //File name to store
        $fileNameToStore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
        //Upload File
        $path = $request->file('file')->storeAS('public/excels', $fileNameToStore);


    }


    $this->validate($request, [
        'file' => 'required|mimes:xlsx,xls',
    ]);

    $products = Excel::toArray(new ProductsImport(), $request->file('file'));

    foreach($products[0] as $row) {
        //  dd($row[1].' '.$row[2]);
        $arr[] = [
            // If uncomment this id from here, remove [0] from foreach
            // 'id' => $row[0], 
            'image' => $row[1],
            'title' => $row[2],
            'slug' => $row[3],
            'text' => $row[4],
            'brand_id' => $row[5],
            'category_id' => $row[6],
        ];
    }

    if(!empty($arr)){
        DB::table('products')->insert($arr);
    }

    return back()->with('success', 'Excel file uploaded to database successfully');

}
```

Comment: Column name are dynamic and it will change want to read that column name and use the same. Got an option of HeadingRowFormatter but confused how to implement it

Answer (score 0):

So whatever you're doing with the row this should work.

I would assume for each row of the excel file you're creating a new model.

```
 public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new Whatever([
            'Mat_Type-1'  => $row['mat_type_1'],
            'Column_Name-1'  => $row['column_name_1'],
            'Column_Name-2'  => $row['column_name_2'],
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Add in your import file this line
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Importable;
and implenets it like this
class Import implements ToModel,WithHeadingRow